# Can JQuery select by a <label>'s text or enumerate its attributes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting:

```
$('label[text="someValue"])
```

but am getting an empty set returned, most probably since text isn't an attribute.

Is it possible to select by the element's text or inner html?

**Edit:** `:contains("someValue)` is not strict enough, since it will return any matches of someValue as a substring.

Is there a way to enumerate all the element's attributes to investigate/interrogate them during debugging/execution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *Is there a way to enumerate all the element's attributes* ? You can iterate over an object's properties with `for(var prop in obj)`. Is this what you mean? With Firebug or directly in Chrome, you can also get a listing of an object with `console.dir(obj)`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see what a list of attributes set for that element. The `for` loop looks like a good way to do it. Thanks Felix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select them all and then filter down to a smaller subset by using `filter`:

```
$('label').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "someValue";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this:

```
    $.each($("#form label"), function() {
        var nodes = this.attributes;
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
        {
          alert(nodes[i].nodeName);
         alert(nodes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function for getting an element's text:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
var labelText = $('.parentClass label').html();
```

What attributes would you add to a label?  You could assign variables to attributes of the label (i'd usually want the for attribute if I was working with labels):

```
var labelAttr = $('.parentClass label').attr('for');
```

Comment: `text()` might be better than `html()`. If the `label` has an `input` element inside, the first one would return the HTML of that input, whereas the latter would only return the text.

Comment: I want to enumerate all the element's attributes. I almost always use a `for` but this label isn't for an input and the additional functionality of the focus inteferes with other functionality on the page.

Comment: Check out answer below...does exactly what you want.